# How to remove double quotes from Json string data using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

My jQuery script as below:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:url, 
    data:'action=getStatus', 
}).done(function(response){ 
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

    var test = data['visitor_chart'];
})
```

My jQuery.ajax return response in below form:

```
"{"visitor_chart":"{y: 3, label: \"2015-07-21\"}, {y: 1, label: \"2015-07-29\"}, {y: 1, label: \"2015-07-30\"}, {y: 1, label: \"2015-08-01\"}","visitor_count":6,"enquiry_count":1}"
```

After `parseJSON` I got `data['visitor_chart']` in below form:

```
"{y: 3, label: "2015-07-21"},{y: 1, label: "2015-07-29"},{y: 1, label: "2015-07-30"},{y: 1, label: "2015-08-01"}"
```

but I want to strip first and last quote from this string.

How to do that?

Comment: This makes no sense, you either have valid JSON that is parsed without error, and you get an object, or you have invalid JSON that can't be parsed and just produce an error.

Comment: In my script there is no error, it works fine. But I want to use `data['visitor_chart']`  in an API as a argument, for this I want to remove  first and last quotes.

Comment: It seems like an utterly strange result, but have you tried parsing it again, as in `jQuery.parseJSON(data['visitor_chart'])`

Answer (score 2):

to replace first quote :

```
str=str.replace(/^"/, "");
```

to replace last quote :

```
str=str.replace(/"$/, "");
```

[Verified here. It's working](https://jsfiddle.net/ec14w7dz/2/)

Comment: @Vinaya Maheshwari Please look at my edited answer. I have verified it.

Comment: Your example puts single quotes around the double quotes, which means you did not actually solve this issue or provide a relevant answer. I also tested your solution and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use also replaceAll

```
var test = data['visitor_chart'];

console.log(test.replaceAll('"', ''));
```